# VueJS POST 404 Not Found

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

My aim is to run my Quasar app to other devices connected to the Local Area Network. I managed to run them as expected although, when I was logging in to the website, I am having this error `POST http://10.0.0.20:8080/MyComposer/?submitId=3 404 (Not Found)` despite working
fine on my localhost before. Why is it not reading the Classes in my index.php at the backend folder properly?

P.S. I don't know if this could solve my problem but when I used phpinfo() to debug, I noticed that the REQUEST_METHOD there is GET instead of POST. Is it possible to swap them? I'll try whatever you guys give me.

Console

```
General
Request URL: http://10.0.0.20:8080/MyComposer/?submitId=3
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 10.0.0.20:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 151
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 28 Jul 2020 12:18:12 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Powered-By: Express

Request Headers
Accept: application/json, text/plain, 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 49
Content-Type: application/json
Host: 10.0.0.20:8080
Origin: http://10.0.0.20:8080
Referer: http://10.0.0.20:8080/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36
```

Headers.php

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://10.0.0.20:8080/'); //OR EITHER http://10.0.0.20:8080/ OR .$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Max-Age: 3600');
if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
    exit(0);
}
```

store.js

```
   actions: {
      LOGIN (context, payload) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          axios
            .post('/MyComposer/', payload, {
              headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
              params: {
                submitId: 3
              }
            })
```

index.php

```
<?php
require 'Classes/Headers.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

echo 'Hello!';
phpinfo();

use Classes\SubjectClass;
use Classes\TestClass;
use Classes\AnswerClass;
use Classes\LoginClass;
use Classes\RegisterClass;
use Classes\TeacherClass;
use Classes\StudentClass;
use Classes\AccountClass;
use Classes\AccessClass;
use Classes\SchoolClass;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $addsubject = new SubjectClass();
    $addsubject->addSubject();
    $addtest = new TestClass();
    $addtest->addTest();
    $submitTest = new AnswerClass();
    $submitTest->submitTest();
    $submitLoginData = new LoginClass();
    $submitLoginData->submitLoginData();
    $addAccountData = new RegisterClass();
    $addAccountData->addAccountData();
    $addSchool = new SchoolClass();
    $addSchool->addSchool();
}
```

Comment: When you open the Developer Tools in your browser and check the Console and Network, do you see that the request is being made? Could you add a screenshot of the response headers to your question in case you see the request is being handled.

Comment: I updated the question now. Hope you can help me with this one.

Comment: If you directly enter "http://10.0.0.20:8080/MyComposer/?submitId=3" into your browser and hit submit, you get something else then a 404?

Comment: Nothing else, just 404 Not Found.

Comment: Which means your JS code is fine but your local server setup needs to be checked. The port is most likely right as you would receive a timeout in other cases. Which web server are you using? Do you use virtual directories or is your "MyComposer" directory located in the web server root directory?

Comment: I am using Apache as my web server. And yes, my `MyComposer` folder is located inside the htdocs folder inside Xampp. I didn't do anything else, other than changing the localhost with my IP Address because it was needed in order for me to connect my app to other devices in the Local Area Network.

Comment: Could you have a look at your httpd.conf and check if Apache is listening to localhost only or all addresses? In your case that should mean it should read `Listen 8080`.

Comment: I looked at it and it says `Listen 80`. Should I change it to `Listen 8080`? If I do, it gives this error upon startup: `Problem detected!
Port 8080 in use by "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" with PID 3808!
Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port`

Comment: In that case get rid of the `:8080` both in your AJAX call and in the Headers.php. You are accessing the wrong web server, you want Apache to handle the request but instead forward it to your node webserver.

Comment: I tried that earlier but it doesn't work for me as well. If I enter 10.0.0.20 ONLY in the browser, it redirects me to the Xampp folder directory.

Comment: Which is the default config of XAMPP: there is an index.php in the htdocs folder that forwards you to "http://localhost/dashboard/" if no other path is given. If your "MyComposer" folder is located directly in the "htdocs" folder, calling "http://localhost/MyComposer" will take you to the correct directory.

Comment: Yes, it does. So, what should I do? Go back with using localhost or relocate my `MyComposer` folder? Because if I used localhost, it won't be recognized by my other devices.

Comment: You simply use the path `http://10.0.0.20/MyComposer/` in your script which will make sure that others are also accessing the right webserver (=Apache) on your machine.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much, man! Took me almost a week to solve this problem. This comment should be the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused not by a coding error but due to two webservers being installed on the affected system, a XAMPP installation running on the default port 80 and a Node.Js server running on port 8080.

To diagnose the problem we first copypasted the URL being used in the script into a browser window which gave the same 404 HTTP error. This excluded the option that the `axios.post()` method caused the behavior.

Next the basic HTTP port assignment was tested. Calling the address `http://10.0.0.20` (user's IP inside the local network) gave the correct XAMPP homepage. When checking the `httpd.conf` and in it the `Listen` setting (which should have been `Listen 8080`) we saw the Apache was using the default HTTP port isntead. Changing it to 8080 (as was used in the script) and restarting Apache resulted in the server not starting with the error:

> Problem detected! Port 8080 in use by "C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node.exe" with PID 3808! Apache WILL NOT start without
> the configured ports free! You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure
> the blocking application or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel
> to listen on a different port.

It was now sure that messed up ports were the cause of the problem. Removing the `:8080` from the scripts made sure the requests were sent to the right server.